# How to prevent sending of hostname via DHCP?

Tags: macos, dns, network

I am trying to prevent OS X from sending its hostname to the DHCP server. For example, in OpenSuse systems there is DHCLIENT_HOSTNAME_OPTION="AUTO".

I cannot find a similar option in OS X for this, does somebody know more?

Comment: What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: On the computer there are 4 virtual interfaces 3 of them are configured with dhcp. The 4th one uses static addressing. The dns record is linked to the 4th interface.
But everytime an interface is restarted the record dns is changed as well. So sometimes the hostname points to 10.x.x.x and some other time it points to 192.168.x.x.

I'd rather not touch the named server.

Comment: Doesn't this sound more like you should look into telling your DHCP server to treat these three mac-adresses specially?

Comment: Yes probably but I was wandering if it was possible to make the change on the client.
By the way are there any dhclient.conf-like files in mac os X ?

Comment: I do not know. In my opinion the most robust solution is server side.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to answer the opposite question: why does my Mac NOT send a hostname in DHCP requests.

After discovering that [some Macs send hostnames and others do not](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3177321), I found the cause in my case: spaces in the Computer Name.

For the gory details, see [my Server Fault posting](https://serverfault.com/a/558015/132219). if you don't want your computer to send a hostname, you could put a space or another unusual character in the Computer Name, and that should do it.